# How to do the same operation Matlab's function polyvaln does but in excel?

Tags: excel, matlab

I have installed Matlab just for the sake of fitting a 2nd degree polynomial for y(COP of a heat pump) dependent on x1(external air temperature) and x2(partial load rate of a heat pump) variables.

The point here is not to use perfect Matlab code, but to generate a polynomial which I can then use further in my EXCEL calculations.

Matlab code (I have included the whole dataset for x and y):

```
x = [7  17.1806179;
7   17.96173559;
7   18.7594434;
7   19.61383408;
7   20.52629015;
7   21.43874623;
7   22.3512023;
7   23.26365837;
7   24.17611444;
7   25.08857051;
7   26.00102658;
7   26.91348265;
7   27.82593872;
7   28.73839479;
7   29.65085086;
7   30.56330693;
7   31.475763;
7   32.38821907;
7   33.30067514;
7   34.21313121;
7   35.12558729;
7   36.03804336;
7   36.95049943;
7   37.8629555;
7   38.77541157;
7   39.68786764;
7   40.60032371;
7   41.51277978;
7   42.42523585;
7   43.33769192;
7   44.25014799;
7   45.16260406;
7   46.07506013;
7   46.9875162;
7   47.89997227;
7   48.81242835;
7   49.72488442;
7   50.63734049;
7   51.54979656;
7   52.46225263;
7   53.3747087;
7   54.28716477;
7   55.19962084;
7   56.11207691;
7   57.02453298;
7   57.93698905;
7   58.84944512;
7   59.76190119;
7   60.67435726;
7   61.58681334;
7   62.49926941;
7   63.41172548;
7   64.32418155;
7   65.23663762;
7   66.14909369;
7   67.06154976;
7   67.97400583;
7   68.8864619;
7   69.79891797;
7   70.71137404;
7   71.62383011;
7   72.53628618;
7   73.44874225;
7   74.36119832;
7   75.2736544;
7   76.18611047;
7   77.09856654;
7   78.01102261;
7   78.92347868;
7   79.83593475;
7   80.74839082;
7   81.66084689;
7   82.57330296;
7   83.48575903;
7   84.3982151;
7   85.31067117;
7   86.22312724;
7   87.13558331;
7   88.04803938;
7   88.96049546;
7   89.87295153;
7   90.7854076;
7   91.69786367;
7   92.61031974;
7   93.14949833;
2   17.17256958;
2   18.03097345;
2   18.94265756;
2   19.79538206;
2   20.39216567;
2   21.18042765;
2   22.16981212;
2   22.96926239;
2   23.98652031;
2   25.73884821;
2   26.65053232;
2   27.56221643;
2   28.47390054;
2   29.38558465;
2   30.29726877;
2   31.20895288;
2   32.12063699;
2   33.0323211;
2   33.94400521;
2   34.85568932;
2   35.76737343;
2   36.67905754;
2   37.59074166;
2   38.50242577;
2   40.18075334;
2   41.2374781;
2   42.14916221;
2   43.06084632;
2   43.97253043;
2   44.88421455;
2   45.79589866;
2   46.70758277;
2   47.61926688;
2   48.53095099;
2   49.47716859;
2   50.35431921;
2   51.26600332;
2   52.17768744;
2   53.08937155;
2   54.00105566;
2   54.91273977;
2   55.82442388;
2   56.73610799;
2   57.6477921;
2   58.55947621;
2   59.52853905;
2   61.29452855;
2   62.20621266;
2   63.11789677;
2   64.02958088;
2   64.94126499;
2   65.8529491;
2   66.76463322;
2   67.67631733;
2   68.58800144;
2   70.41136966;
2   71.32305377;
2   72.23473788;
2   73.14642199;
2   74.0581061;
2   74.96979022;
2   75.88147433;
2   76.79315844;
2   77.70484255;
2   78.46368088;
2   79.19668928;
2   80.13890826;
2   81.03189755;
2   82.01462198;
2   82.9263061;
2   83.83799021;
2   84.74967432;
2   85.66135843;
2   86.57304254;
2   87.48472665;
2   88.39641076;
2   89.30809487;
2   90.21977899;
2   91.1314631;
2   92.04314721;
2   92.95483132;
2   93.83198194;
2   94.77819954;
2   95.66916356;
2   96.60156776;
2   97.51325188;
2   98.42493599;
2   99.3366201;
2   99.98308701;
-7  22.17499214;
-7  23.08667625;
-7  23.99836036;
-7  24.91004447;
-7  25.82172858;
-7  26.73341269;
-7  27.64509681;
-7  28.55678092;
-7  29.46846503;
-7  30.38014914;
-7  31.29183325;
-7  32.20351736;
-7  33.11520147;
-7  34.02688558;
-7  34.9385697;
-7  35.85025381;
-7  36.76193792;
-7  37.67362203;
-7  38.58530614;
-7  39.49699025;
-7  40.40867436;
-7  41.32035847;
-7  42.23204259;
-7  43.1437267;
-7  44.05541081;
-7  44.96709492;
-7  45.87877903;
-7  46.79046314;
-7  47.70214725;
-7  48.61383136;
-7  49.52551548;
-7  50.43719959;
-7  51.3488837;
-7  52.26056781;
-7  53.17225192;
-7  54.08393603;
-7  54.99562014;
-7  55.90730425;
-7  56.81898837;
-7  57.73067248;
-7  58.64235659;
-7  59.5540407;
-7  60.46572481;
-7  61.37740892;
-7  62.28909303;
-7  63.20077714;
-7  64.11246126;
-7  65.02414537;
-7  65.93582948;
-7  66.84751359;
-7  67.7591977;
-7  68.67088181;
-7  69.58256592;
-7  70.49425003;
-7  71.40593414;
-7  72.31761826;
-7  73.22930237;
-7  74.14098648;
-7  75.05267059;
-7  75.9643547;
-7  76.87603881;
-7  77.78772292;
-7  78.69940703;
-7  79.61109115;
-7  80.52277526;
-7  81.43445937;
-7  82.34614348;
-7  83.25782759;
-7  84.1695117;
-7  85.08119581;
-7  85.99287992;
-7  86.90456404;
-7  87.81624815;
-7  88.72793226;
-7  89.63961637;
-7  90.55130048;
-7  91.46298459;
-7  92.3746687;
-7  93.28635281;
-7  94.19803693;
-7  95.10972104;
-7  96.02140515;
-7  96.93308926;
-7  97.84477337;
-7  98.75645748;
-7  99.66814159;
-15 26.15325008;
-15 27.06493419;
-15 27.9766183;
-15 28.88830241;
-15 29.79998652;
-15 30.71167063;
-15 31.62335475;
-15 32.53503886;
-15 33.44672297;
-15 34.35840708;
-15 35.27009119;
-15 36.1817753;
-15 37.09345941;
-15 38.00514352;
-15 38.91682764;
-15 39.82851175;
-15 40.74019586;
-15 41.65187997;
-15 42.56356408;
-15 43.47524819;
-15 44.3869323;
-15 45.29861641;
-15 46.21030053;
-15 47.12198464;
-15 48.03366875;
-15 48.94535286;
-15 49.85703697;
-15 50.76872108;
-15 51.68040519;
-15 52.5920893;
-15 53.50377342;
-15 54.41545753;
-15 55.32714164;
-15 56.23882575;
-15 57.15050986;
-15 58.06219397;
-15 58.97387808;
-15 59.88556219;
-15 60.79724631;
-15 61.70893042;
-15 62.62061453;
-15 63.53229864;
-15 64.44398275;
-15 65.35566686;
-15 66.26735097;
-15 67.17903508;
-15 68.0907192;
-15 69.00240331;
-15 69.91408742;
-15 70.82577153;
-15 71.73745564;
-15 72.64913975;
-15 73.56082386;
-15 74.47250797;
-15 75.38419208;
-15 76.2958762;
-15 77.20756031;
-15 78.11924442;
-15 79.03092853;
-15 79.94261264;
-15 80.85429675;
-15 81.76598086;
-15 82.67766497;
-15 83.58934909;
-15 84.5010332;
-15 85.41271731;
-15 86.32440142;
-15 87.23608553;
-15 88.14776964;
-15 89.05945375;
-15 89.97113786;
-15 90.88282198;
-15 91.79450609;
-15 92.7061902;
-15 93.61787431;
-15 94.52955842;
-15 95.44124253;
-15 96.35292664;
-15 97.26461075;
-15 98.17629487;
-15 99.08797898;
-15 99.83390234;];

y = [3.904076645;
3.990561728;
4.075012137;
4.162635296;
4.244361744;
4.319156203;
4.387711873;
4.45106855;
4.509226236;
4.561491731;
4.609598032;
4.65389174;
4.692293257;
4.727575379;
4.759738106;
4.78704844;
4.812972377;
4.834390521;
4.854768866;
4.871334618;
4.886167372;
4.898227331;
4.908554292;
4.916455058;
4.923316025;
4.928790594;
4.931145768;
4.931767945;
4.934816318;
4.932319099;
4.930861679;
4.930097459;
4.924827445;
4.921637028;
4.915673815;
4.909017403;
4.902707591;
4.89535798;
4.88766177;
4.879272362;
4.870189754;
4.861107146;
4.85098474;
4.841555533;
4.831086527;
4.820270922;
4.809801916;
4.797946513;
4.787477507;
4.775275505;
4.764459899;
4.752604496;
4.741442292;
4.729240289;
4.718078084;
4.705529482;
4.694020678;
4.681472076;
4.670309871;
4.658454468;
4.646599064;
4.634743661;
4.622888258;
4.611726053;
4.59987065;
4.588708445;
4.577199641;
4.566037437;
4.555221832;
4.543713028;
4.533244022;
4.522081818;
4.511959412;
4.501490406;
4.490328201;
4.481245594;
4.470776588;
4.460307582;
4.450878375;
4.441795767;
4.432019961;
4.422590753;
4.413508146;
4.404772137;
4.402823873;
3.524818976;
3.609810722;
3.689460981;
3.748738925;
3.817316516;
3.862326392;
3.926057106;
3.977743907;
4.020230671;
4.120407145;
4.15936273;
4.19449232;
4.226143734;
4.254316969;
4.279359846;
4.301967998;
4.321793608;
4.339532312;
4.354140657;
4.367357731;
4.37814008;
4.387878976;
4.394835331;
4.401443868;
4.411380002;
4.409443675;
4.409443675;
4.409443675;
4.409443675;
4.407356769;
4.401791685;
4.399704779;
4.394139695;
4.388226794;
4.381067546;
4.38266171;
4.369096819;
4.361444829;
4.353792839;
4.345445214;
4.336401953;
4.328054327;
4.318663249;
4.308924352;
4.298837638;
4.288744181;
4.268925314;
4.259186418;
4.24805625;
4.237621719;
4.22823064;
4.217796108;
4.206318123;
4.195535774;
4.184405606;
4.162840907;
4.152754193;
4.142319661;
4.131189494;
4.121450598;
4.110320431;
4.100233717;
4.090842638;
4.079712471;
4.07029877;
4.058982911;
4.048137358;
4.038335048;
4.026844176;
4.02162691;
4.014322738;
4.004931659;
3.995888399;
3.98649732;
3.97884533;
3.96764164;
3.959952889;
3.952882292;
3.943622988;
3.938483981;
3.925225501;
3.919761864;
3.912064326;
3.90648475;
3.896760347;
3.889803992;
3.88249982;
3.875543465;
3.870743581;
3.080432142;
3.128430989;
3.173647293;
3.217124509;
3.25677573;
3.292948773;
3.326339275;
3.356599417;
3.384424835;
3.409815529;
3.432423682;
3.452944927;
3.472074902;
3.488074518;
3.502682862;
3.515552118;
3.526682285;
3.536073364;
3.54442099;
3.551725162;
3.557290245;
3.560420605;
3.565290053;
3.567724777;
3.567724777;
3.567724777;
3.567724777;
3.567724777;
3.566333506;
3.561811876;
3.560072787;
3.555898975;
3.552420797;
3.546160078;
3.542334083;
3.536421182;
3.530160463;
3.523899744;
3.517986842;
3.511030488;
3.504074133;
3.496769961;
3.489465789;
3.481813799;
3.474161809;
3.465814183;
3.457814376;
3.449814568;
3.441466942;
3.433119317;
3.424771692;
3.416424066;
3.407728623;
3.399380998;
3.390685554;
3.381990111;
3.373294668;
3.364947043;
3.356599417;
3.348251792;
3.339904166;
3.331208723;
3.322861098;
3.31486129;
3.305818029;
3.297818221;
3.289818414;
3.281818606;
3.273818798;
3.266166808;
3.258167001;
3.250167193;
3.242515203;
3.235558848;
3.227906858;
3.220254868;
3.213298514;
3.205994342;
3.199037987;
3.191733815;
3.185125278;
3.178168923;
3.171212569;
3.16495185;
3.158691131;
3.153126047;
2.479055293;
2.51627179;
2.554879558;
2.590704783;
2.624790921;
2.655051063;
2.68461557;
2.711397534;
2.736092593;
2.758352928;
2.779569809;
2.799395419;
2.817134123;
2.833133739;
2.847394266;
2.861306975;
2.872437142;
2.882871674;
2.89261057;
2.900958195;
2.907566732;
2.913827451;
2.919740353;
2.922522894;
2.92774016;
2.928783614;
2.930174884;
2.932609609;
2.932609609;
2.932609609;
2.931218338;
2.928783614;
2.928783614;
2.92774016;
2.92321853;
2.921131624;
2.917653446;
2.913479634;
2.909305821;
2.905479826;
2.899914742;
2.896436565;
2.890523664;
2.884610762;
2.879741314;
2.87417623;
2.867915511;
2.861306975;
2.855394073;
2.849481172;
2.843220453;
2.836264098;
2.830003379;
2.823047025;
2.816438488;
2.809829951;
2.802873597;
2.796612877;
2.78861307;
2.781308897;
2.774700361;
2.767744006;
2.761831105;
2.75487475;
2.747918396;
2.740962041;
2.735396958;
2.728092785;
2.721484249;
2.714875712;
2.708614993;
2.700615185;
2.694006648;
2.687398111;
2.681137392;
2.674876673;
2.667920319;
2.662007417;
2.65539888;
2.649485979;
2.643573078;
2.638007994;];

p = polyfitn(x, y, 2);

% Display coefficients
disp('Coefficients:');
disp(p.Coefficients');

% Display the polynomial function with coefficients
disp('Fitted Polynomial Function:');
disp(['y = ' num2str(p.Coefficients(1)) ' + ' num2str(p.Coefficients(2)) ' * x1 + ' num2str(p.Coefficients(3)) ' * x2 + ' ...
      num2str(p.Coefficients(4)) ' * x1^2 + ' num2str(p.Coefficients(5)) ' * x1 * x2 + ' num2str(p.Coefficients(6)) ' * x2^2']);

% Evaluate the fitted polynomial on a grid
x1_grid = linspace(min(x(:, 1)), max(x(:, 1)), 100);
x2_grid = linspace(min(x(:, 2)), max(x(:, 2)), 100);
[X1_grid, X2_grid] = meshgrid(x1_grid, x2_grid);
Y_pred_grid = polyvaln(p, [X1_grid(:), X2_grid(:)]);

% Reshape the prediction for plotting
Y_pred_grid = reshape(Y_pred_grid, size(X1_grid));

% Plot the original data and the fitted polynomial surface
figure;
scatter3(x(:, 1), x(:, 2), y, 'o', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'b');
hold on;
surf(X1_grid, X2_grid, Y_pred_grid, 'FaceAlpha', 0.5, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
xlabel('x1');
ylabel('x2');
zlabel('y');
title('Polynomial Fitting');
legend('Data', 'Fitted Polynomial Surface', 'Location', 'Best');
hold off;

% Evaluate the fitted polynomial for the first row of x
y_pred_first_row = polyvaln(p, x(1, :));


disp(['Predicted value for the first row: ' num2str(y_pred_first_row)]);
disp(['x1 value: ' num2str(x(1, 1))]);
disp(['x2 value: ' num2str(x(1, 2))]);

% Display the full mathematical formula
disp('Full Mathematical Formula:');
disp(['y = ' num2str(p.Coefficients(1)) ' + ' num2str(p.Coefficients(2)) ' * ' num2str(x(1, 1)) ' + ' ...
      num2str(p.Coefficients(3)) ' * ' num2str(x(1, 2)) ' + ' ...
      num2str(p.Coefficients(4)) ' * ' num2str(x(1, 1)^2) ' + ' ...
      num2str(p.Coefficients(5)) ' * ' num2str(x(1, 1) * x(1, 2)) ' + ' ...
      num2str(p.Coefficients(6)) ' * ' num2str(x(1, 2)^2)]);
```

Manual calculation with fitted polynomial gives different result because, from what I am assuming, Matlab's polyvaln function evalutes and probably drops certain coefficients if they don't suit the data accordingly?

For example:

Predicted value for the first row: 4.4267
Calculated value using polynomial expression manually:  301.0271

Comment: `polyfitn` itself looks like a [FileExchange function](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34765-polyfitn) not something in-built, which means you can look at the source code. I'm not sure what you mean by it "drops certain coefficients if they don't suit the data"? Can you just describe mathematically what you'd like to achieve in Excel? It's unclear to me what your last sentence means and what you're comparing using "prediction" vs "manual" calculation

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you have a set of observed values for a response `y` given two variables `x1` and `x2`, and you want to fit some polynomial function to this data such as

```
a1*x1^2 + a2*x2^2 + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + c = y
```

You can do this in Excel using the [Solver add-in](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040), as follows:

- Define cells on your worksheet for the coefficients in the function e.g. `a1`, `a2`, `b1` etc
- Create a column in which you calculate the result of the function for each of your observations, i.e. each pair of `x1, x2`, using the values in the above cells as the coefficients
- Create a column which calculates the difference between each function result and the corresponding `y` observation
- Place a `SUMSQ` function in another cell that calculates the sum of squares of the differences - this is your objective cell
- Use Solver to minimise the objective cell value by changing the coefficient cell values.

You're right to be aware of the risk of overfitting by having too many coefficients in your function - you can try and handle this by either removing coefficients from the Solver configuration (and setting them to zero) and seeing if your error gets much worse, or by starting with fewer coefficients (setting the rest to zero) and seeing if the error gets significantly better when you add more. You haven't said whether you need to automate this process for multiple runs or datasets but if you need to you can automate Solver from Excel VBA macros.